# Cannot get token from Huawei HMS push kit

Tags: push-notification, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

error message as below

> **[getToken] Error/Exception: {"nativeStackAndroid":[],"userInfo":null,"message":"907122036: no
> right","code":"907122045","line":2568,"column":45,"sourceURL":"http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.huaweipush.letsapp&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true"}**

Comment: I have followed these steps:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/commonerror-0000001059816656

And completed below preparations:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-config-agc-0000001050170137

Answer (score 2):

> [getToken] Error/Exception: {"nativeStackAndroid":[],"userInfo":null,"message":"907122036: no right","code":"907122045","line":2568,"column":45,"sourceURL":"http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.huaweipush.letsapp&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true"}

The error code indicates that the Push Kit are not enabled. As a result, have no permission to obtain the token. How to enable the Push Kit, pls refer to the [this docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-config-agc-0000001050170137#section9471122085218).

1. Sign in to AppGallery Connect and click **My projects**.
   [image]
2. Find and click the desired project in the project list, and click the app for which you need to set Push Kit parameters.
   [image]
3. Go to **Project settings** > **Manage APIs** and enable Push Kit.
   [image]
4. Go to **Grow** > **Push Kit** and click **Enable** now. In the dialog box that is displayed, click **OK**.
   [image]
5. Enable the precise messaging function.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Here below is some checkpoints for the above issue.

1. First ensure you have **enabled the push kit in AppGallery Console**
2. Please check whether you are providing **correct app id** or not:

   String appId = AGConnectServicesConfig.fromContext(MainActivity.this).getString("client/app_id");
   pushtoken = HmsInstanceId.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getToken(**appId**, "HCM");
3. It is recommended that the **getToken method** be called **in the onCreate method** of the first Activity class after app startup. Implement the corresponding listeners for getToken API and observe the logs.
4. **Device**: Non-Huawei phones **must have HMS Core (APK) installed** (which can be downloaded from HUAWEI AppGallery). There is no restriction on Huawei phones.
5. **Network**: The phone is connected to the network and the connection is stable.
6. **EMUI version**: EMUI 4.0 and EMUI 4.1 (for some devices), and EMUI 5.0 or later It is recommended that you use a device running EMUI 5.0 or later.